# How to query many to many in Doctrine ORM?

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine

I would like to ask your idea on how to query this kind of many to many scenario in symfony.

Inside my entity Basket, i have this linkable table to the User Entity

**Entity: Basket**

```
/**
     * @var User $users
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\User", cascade={"persist","remove"})
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="basket_users",
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="basket_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")}
     *      )
     */
    protected $users;
```

I successfully added the data in my table basket_users that display like this
**Table: basket_users**

```
------------------------
basket_id  |  user_id
------------------------
2          |   15
2          |   10
2          |    3
------------------------
```

I have this code to display Table:Basket data list

```
 $sample = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Basket')->findByUserId($userId));
```

and here is the repository for findByUserId().

```
public function findByUserId($id)
    {
        $qb = $this->getQueryBuilderByUser($id)
            ->addCriteria($this->getOrderedByLastSentCriteria(Criteria::DESC));

        $result = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();

        return empty($result) ? null : $result;
    }

public function getQueryBuilderByUser($userId)
{
    return $this->createQueryBuilder(self::ALIAS)
        ->select(self::ALIAS.', u')
        ->innerJoin(self::ALIAS.'.users', 'u')
        ->where('u.id = :userId')
        ->setParameter('userId', $userId);
}

private function getOrderedByLastSentCriteria($order = Criteria::DESC)
{
    return Criteria::create()->orderBy([self::ALIAS.'.scheduleAt' => $order]);
}
```

This code is successfully display the list of Table:Basket. Here is the scenario that I don't know if possible to query. I have a user id that is 3. that code above will display the Basket list.
When I use dump() to get the symfony result

```
array:1 [▼
  0 => Basket {#1090 ▼
    #id: 2
    #title: "king"
    #price: 200
    #title: "Test"
    #users: PersistentCollection {#1088 ▶}
    #scheduleAt: DateTime {#1068 ▶}
  }
]
```

How can I include in my query that will display the user_id 10 and user_id 15? In my persistCollection under users. It only display the user 3 in my collection.

**Update**

```
User {#813 ▼
    #id: 3
    #createdAt: DateTime {#817 ▶}
    #updatedAt: DateTime {#816 ▶}
    #profile: null
    #username: "ace"
    #email: "sample@gmail.com"
    #plainPassword: null
    #lastLogin: DateTime {#818 ▶}
    #confirmationToken: null
    #passwordRequestedAt: null
    #groups: null
    #roles: array:2 [▶]
```

**new Update**

So far I already got an idea by using this `$qb->expr()->in` but the problem now It only display user id 3. see my code and comment

```
 public function listUsers($id){

        //user_id = 3
        $result = $this->findByUserId($id);
        $idList = [];
        if($result){
            foreach ($result as $opentok){
               $idList[] = $opentok->getId();
            }
        }

        // basket_id = 2
        // idList = [2]
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('er');
        $qb->where($qb->expr()->in('er.id', $idList));

        dump($qb->getQuery()->getResult());
        exit;
}
```

I use the previous code findByUserId($id) to get the id of Basket that is basketId 2. When I get the list, I put it an array `$idList = [];` to store the id and then add to my query

```
 $qb->where($qb->expr()->in('er.id', $idList));
```

since that query like selecting the Basket table like this one

```
Select * from AppBundle:Basket where id = 2
```

This display the basket but when I view the user. It only display user id 3.

Comment: You are asking a Doctrine question, not Symfony.

Comment: sorry. I will change the question.

Comment: What do you see if you `print_r` or `dump` `$result[0]['users']` ?

Comment: @ChrisLam I update my post. under user. that will be the display. It only display user 3

Comment: You do have a condition to filter by user_id: `->where('u.id = :userId')`

Comment: So When you do `$basket->getUsers()` it only returns the user#3 ? Are you sure of that?

Comment: yes. the value of :userId is 3. that's the reason why it only display  the user 3. I want to include the user 10 and user 15 when i query the userid 3. Is this possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filter query using SQL IN statement in doctrine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12968775/filter-query-using-sql-in-statement-in-doctrine)

Comment: @jkucharovic I try that one but it only display one user for basket. that userid 3

Comment: @user3818576 Have you tried `->where('u.id IN (:users)')->setParameter('users', [3, 10, 15])`?

Comment: @jkucharovic I update my post.